# Which redirect status should be used to preserve Google Analytics page views data?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, google-analytics

I would like to set up a redirect so that when user requests: http://www.fareham.ac.uk/chequers they are redirected to the long URL: http://www.fareham.ac.uk/the-college/campus-facilities/chequers-restaurant

I've installed the [Path redirect module](http://drupal.org/project/path_redirect), which offers the following redirect status options:

- 300 Multiple Choices
- 301 Moved Permanently
- 302 Found
- 303 See Other
- 304 Not Modified
- 305 Use Proxy
- 307 Temporary Redirect

Which option should I use to achieve desired effect **AND** ensure that GA page views data is based on long URL not short URL.

I want to provide visitors with a short URL for convenience, but I don't want to mess up the page views statistics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use 301 redirects for this sort of use case.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I used https://www.drupal.org/project/field_redirection that looks quite interesting. You have to create a custom content type and it still uses 301 and other HTTP redirection methods, but the redirect is performed by a field in the node itself, so GA should track it. I am implementing this on our live site tomorrow, and will be updating this post for future reference. Wish me luck!

...still a great tool so you don't have to tamper with settings.php or .htaccess, but GA doesn't track it :(